# static プロパティを初期化したい

Tags: c#

抽象クラス `Super` を継承した `Sub` クラスがあります。
`Sub.All` プロパティで `Sub.One` と `Sub.Two` のインスタンスを取得したいです。

```
abstract class Super<T> where T : Super<T>
{
    private readonly int value;
    private static List<T> list = new List<T>();

    public static List<T> All { get { return list; } }

    protected Super(int value)
    {
        this.value = value;
        list.Add((T)this);
    }
}

class Sub : Super<Sub>
{
    public static Sub One = new Sub(1);
    public static Sub Two = new Sub(2);

    private Sub(int value)
        : base(value)
    {
    }
}
```

次のようにすれば `Sub` の静的コンストラクタが実行されるので、実現できることは理解しています。1 行目がない場合でも実現できる方法が知りたいです。

```
var instance = Sub.One; // これがなくても実現してほしい
var all = Sub.All; // Sub.One と Sub.Two のインスタンスが格納されていてほしい
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> var all = Sub.All; // Sub.One と Sub.Two のインスタンスが格納されていてほしい
> ```

ソースコード上は`Sub.All`と記述していますが、実体としては`Super<Sub>.All`であり、コンパイル時にそのように解釈されます。そのため、`Sub`静的コンストラクターが実行される理由が存在しません。

やや強引となりますが、`Super`静的コンストラクター内で強制的に`Sub`静的コンストラクターを呼び出すことでしょうか。

```
static Super() {
    System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers.RunClassConstructor(typeof(T).TypeHandle);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

綺麗な解法ではないことは自覚しつつ... 下記コードのように子クラス`Sub`で親クラス`Super<Sub>`のプロパティを“隠ぺい(hiding)”してしまえば、お望みの挙動が得られるようです。

```
class Sub : Super<Sub>
{
    public static Sub One = new Sub(1);
    public static Sub Two = new Sub(2);

    new public static List<Sub> All { get { return Super<Sub>.All; } }

    // (略)
}
```

https://wandbox.org/permlink/W2hoFpM3GqF4Z0v1

C#言語では、“該当クラスへアクセス”されたタイミングでstaticメンバの初期化が行われます。このクラス`Sub`へアクセス判定が（少なくとも私には）直感的ではなく、親クラスから継承しているプロパティ(`Super<T>.All`)アクセスでは判定外となる仕様のようです。前掲の解決策では、子クラス自身でプロパティ(`Sub.All`)をあえて再定義し、その内部処理は親クラスへ単純委譲しています。